# Arduino как преобразователь интерфейса

Tags: железо, usb

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, можно ли использовать Freeduino как преобразователь интерфейса USB <-> RS-485 (RS-232). Ведь микросхема-преобразователь там установлена. Спасибо!

Comment: Хотя бы ссылку на схему дали -- этих арудин много. А реально -- вряд ли. Для этого нужна "эта самая микросхема" + приёмо-передатчики для RS-485 (или, хотя бы RS-232) на внешний разъём.

Comment: @drdaeman в ответе @savro у меня комментарии кончились. А здесь заодно видно, о чём спрашивает @Колобуня :). Я там уже перестал понимать о чём идёт речь. За то, что не понял комментарий, приношу извинения.

Comment: Схема вот http://freeduino.ru/arduino/files/freeduino_2009_scheme.gif Насколько знаю не отличается от Ардуины.
Большое спасибо всем за ответы, дело в том, что хотелось бы обмениваться информацией с некоторыми устройствами, имеющими на борту RS-485, а стандартного преобразователя у меня нет (для случая RS-232 нет и COM-порта). Вот и хотел использовать Freeduino.

Answer (score 2):

Можно 1 ножка RX 5 ножка это TX.
Имеется ввиду мс FT232RL , припаивайся и юзай.
Если нужны остальные сигналы (RTS CTS DTR DSR), качай даташит на FT232 и смотри, а у андурины схема включения преобразователя стандарта по даташиту.

Comment: Переведите, пожалуйста, на русский язык то, что написали. А для @Колобуня -- см. стр. 27 http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf -- это пример использования FT232R в качестве конвертора usb-rs485. Обратить внимание на мелкосхему, обозначенную на схеме как "RS485 LEVEL CONVERTER" (её, как я понимаю, на плате Arudino быть не должно)

Comment: а что переводить?
подпивайся к ножкам и используй как преобразователь микросхем включена согласно даташиту .

Comment: @savro я думаю, что @Колобуня нужно немного не это ("это" -- преобразование arudino в пару fr232rl + блок питания. Что-то вроде добычи изюма из булочек). Нафига вполне нормальную платку превращать в полуфабрикат преобразователя (не забывайте про Sipex SP481)

Вопрос на засыпку: Вы сами стали бы так делать?

Comment: Суть в том что ничего не нарушается, и плата будет дальше работать.

Сам так делал правда не с андуриной, а с другим устройством,нужно было прошить тюнер, а ком порта не было, взял устройство с 232 на борту, припаял 3 проводка, прошил тюнер отпаял дальше устройство использовалось по назначению.

Comment: на FT232 собран преобразователь юсб-232 или не так?

Comment: tl;dr: Если нужен банальный UART — вытаскиваем атмегу, тыкаемся в 1-2 пины (RX/TX) и землю, и все.

Comment: @drdaeman Маразм крепчает? В дискуссию включается ещё один юный техник, систематично прогуливавший физику. "Штык в землю" -- это круто. Как уровни 0В и 5В превратить в уровни -3В...-15В и +3В...+15В с запрещённым диапазоном -3В...+3В (RS-232)? Про RS-485 вспоминать пока не будем, уважаемые "юные техники".

@savro Кроме ft232 там ещё какие-то детальки есть.

Comment: Если нужны родные уровни берем max232 в родном включении.
Но в большинстве случаев достаточно 0-5 в.
@alexlz Хотите подискутировать про электронику создавайте отдельную тему и обсудим.
А то что Вы пытаетесь пиписькой мерятся, то она еще у вас не выросла.

Comment: @savro. Фиксируем оскорбление. Дискуссию с малолетним хулиганом прекращаю.

Comment: @alexlz: Зочем ви тrавите? Я же специально написал — UART. А не RS232. Понятно, что не совсем оно по теме вопроса, но мало ли что ОП имеет в виду.